# Pandas SettingWithCopyWarning over re-ordering column's categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

This is the [custom function](https://github.com/ghostiek/RandSnippets/blob/master/Python/seaborn/top_n_barplot.py) I'm making

```
"""
Returns a seaborn barplot of the top/bottom n elements
Parameters:
n        -- Number of elements to use.
top      -- True gets the top n elements, False will get the bottom n 
elements. Default: True.
**kwargs -- Dictionary of values that satisfy the parameters of the barplot. 
Minimum necessary is data, x, y, estimator.
Return:
seaborn.barplot object
"""
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def top_n_barplot(n, top = True, **kwargs):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError("n cannot be smaller than 1.")

    #Get necessary data
    data = kwargs["data"]
    x = kwargs["x"]
    y = kwargs["y"]
    estimator = kwargs["estimator"]

    #Get all the results and sort
    result = data.groupby(x)[y].apply(estimator).sort_values()

    if top:
        result = result[-n:]
    else:
        result = result[:n]

    #Filter according to necessary data
    top_x = result.index    
    newdata = data.loc[data[x].isin(top_x.values)]
    #Make values categorical and order them
    newdata[x] = pd.Categorical(newdata[x], categories=top_x, ordered=True)
    #Assign new data to use for plot
    kwargs["data"] = newdata

    return sns.barplot(**kwargs)
```

Line 38 is giving me the a SettingWithCopyWarning.

```
newdata[x] = pd.Categorical(newdata[x], categories=top_x, ordered=True)
```

Here's full warning:

```
C:\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

Furthermore I also tried something different to see what I was doing wrong so I changed line 38 to `newdata.loc[:,x] = newdata.loc[:,x].astype("category")` 
 in the hopes of then re-ordering it using [this function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.reorder_categories.html) later. However, I still ended up with the exact same warning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My function is working as intended, but I really want to understand why I'm getting this warning.

Comment: Problem is with `newdata = data.loc[data[x].isin(top_x.values)]`, need `newdata = data.loc[data[x].isin(top_x.values)].copy()`

Comment: I was too tunnel-visioned on that specific line number. Thanks a lot